# Getting results in O(1) : Java

Tags: java, performance, collections, interface, time-complexity

I have java interface with

```
public interface Emp {
           void addEmp(int empId, String dept);

           void updateEmp(int empId, String dept);

           List<EmpDTO> getEmpByDept(String dept);

}
```

Here there is no database connection and we are storing emp data in some java collection

How can I implement all the above three method with the help of collection and with all of the three having time complexity O(1)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Sound like you need a `Map<Integer, EmpDTO>` and a `Map<String, List<EmptDTO>`.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-complexity

Comment: Was asked in interview .. I thought on same lines but only implemented using Map<String,List<EmpDTO>> which later became tricky for me to justify

Comment: @Sagii: you won't be able to implement `updateEmpt` efficiently if you don't also have the other `Map`.

Comment: Yes ... I was thinking on same lines .. But i realised it little later .. I could implement two methods with O(1) but update I could not do .. Now I understand the solution

Comment: @JoachimSauer Will it be really O(1) in this approach? As I can understand, during `updateEmp` call, you also need to remove previous `EmpDTO` from the List, which will not be O(1), I guess.